# Bootstrap 4.x Carousel Problems with White Space & Image Alignment

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've checked previous questions and answers here, and my problem is slightly different. The page gets excessive white space on mobile but not on Desktop. Also, if the mobile view is turned into landscape, the whitespace problem disappears.

The other problem I'm having is with an image in the carousel being cropped in its view to the point that most of the image is not visible. Seems to me the image should be aligned center both vertically and horizontally but with fluid resize still enabled. Is this possible? The gist is that when you look at the image, your seeing the visible parts of it starting from the very center of the image.

Here is the page: https://kianrafiee.github.io/unity/

Here are some screenshots to help show what I mean with the problems I'm facing.

1) On mobile view in Chrome for iOS on an iPhone SE, there is excessive white space under the carousel and in other locations on the page. This problem disappears if the browser is in landscape mode:

white space problem exhibit A
[image: white space problem exhibit A]

white space problem exhibit B
[image: white space problem exhibit B]

landscape mode, problem gone
[image: landscape mode, problem gone]

2) On a Desktop browser, some of the images are of no use because most of the good parts of the image are not visible because of how the carousel crops it. Seems to me the image should be aligned center both vertically and horizontally but with fluid resize still enabled. Is this possible? The gist is that when you look at the image, I want it so you're seeing the visible parts of it starting from the very center of the image.

image cropping problem exhibit A
[image: image cropping problem exhibit A]

image cropping problem gone, when browser is resized to a smaller width
[image: image cropping problem gone, when browser is resized to a smaller width]

3) On a Mac Desktop in a Chrome browser, there is excessive white space under every carousel except the main top one which is causing the grid system to not vertically align to middle each row. These carousels are inside a grid system using the official bootstrap example. I inspected the elements and notice that the size of the container for the carousel image is much larger in height than any of the images in the carousels. But I cannot find what style sheet change I need to implement yet. I used grid alignments from the bootstrap official examples, but it did not fix the problem although it did help a little.

white space problem on desktop causing vertical align to middle not to work exhibit A
[image: white space problem on desktop exhibit A]